# Running multiple versions of Ruby/Rails using Passenger

Tags: ruby-on-rails, passenger

I have been looking into running Rails 2.3.11(1.8.7) and Rails 3(Ruby 1.9) in parallel. The Phusion website has the following recommended path: [Stanadlone Passenger](http://blog.phusion.nl/2010/09/21/phusion-passenger-running-multiple-ruby-versions/)

The other option is to run a separate instance of Apache with mod_rails which hosts the Rails 3. The advantage that I see with this approach is that the new app can be also a standalone app and doesnt need to go via the first app for request routing. That is I can have a url matching reverse proxy which can route requests to Rails 3 or Rails 2.

My questions is which is a better option? Using another Apache with mod_rails to host the second instance or just use a standalone Passenger.

Comment: I am using the first method ie passenger standalone. I don't understand your second method, how do you run multiple instances of apache?

Answer (score 0):

As I know it is impossible. But you can do it using apache and fcgi. Fcgi will not conflict with passenger.
You can even use rvm with fcgi.

Here is example of index.fcgi for fcgi and rvm:

```
#!/usr/bin/env /home/user/.rvm/bin/ruby-1.9.2-p290

ENV['GEM_HOME'] = '/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@app_gemset'
ENV['GEM_PATH'] = '/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@app_gemset:/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global'

ENV['RAILS_ENV'] ||= 'production'


require File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), '../config/environment')


Rack::Handler::FastCGI.run  ...
```